# Type of set theory used in Munkres w.r.t to a question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm doing problems from the first section of Munkres Topology based on set theory notions and it asked to confirm if the following equation is true given sets A,B:

$$A - (A-B) = B$$

Now I said it is true, but I stumbled upon some solutions for this section and the author said that it is not necessarily true and proved it via using the Universal set. Now I was not aware of the universal set in this context so I read up on it and from the quick read I had it said that the Universal set does not exist in Zermelo-Frankael set theory. So would my conclusion that this statement is true stand if we were in ZFC?

Also if it is true I'm not sure I drew the conclusion right. I kind of just treated the sets in an algebraic manner and "carried" through the minus sign, is that how to treat this form of question?

Comment: No, you definitely cannot just "carry" through the minus sign.  You can't just treat sets (in particular, set difference) in an algebraic manner in the same way as in $\mathbb{N},\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q},$ ect.

Comment: then how would I go about treating them?

Comment: You have to think about what the operations *mean*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=\{0,1\}, B=\{1,2\}$, then $A-(A-B)=A-\{0\}=\{0,1\}-\{0\}=\{1\}\neq B$.

Comment: could you explain this a little further. in the (A-B) portion If I have the set {0,1} - {1,2} are we saying that the only element between them is {1}? but then how is {1} - {1} = {1} ?

Comment: @dc3rd it is edited

Comment: why is A-B = {0}? is it because the element that A and B have in common is one, so that is removed from A, which then leaves {0}? So I guess I'm asking that is it the shared element between them that creates that?

Comment: $A-B$ is defined to be $\{x\in A\mid x\notin B\}$, you can then check whether $0,1\in B$.

Comment: That makes sense. What about this whole Universal set idea because it comes up in another question A - (B-A) = A-B.  The solution get's turned into $A-(B-A) = A\cap(U - (B\cap(U - A)))$ and then it was expanded. I've never used the universal U before. can you do it without?

Comment: not understand your question

Comment: I will post it as a new question right now.

Answer (score 0):

$A \setminus (A \setminus B) = \{x \in A: x \notin A \setminus B\}$

$= \{ x \in A: x \notin \{y \in A: y \notin B\}\}$

$= \{x \in A: x: \neg(x \in A$ and $x \notin B)\}$

$= \{x \in A: x \notin A $ or $x \in B$}$

$= \{x \in A: x \in B\}$ since we cannot have both $x \in A$  and $x \notin A$

$= A \cap B$